# How to reset Thunderbird view, because I got this big grey bar in the middle

Tags: thunderbird

I think it's a bug, as I was resizing the messages pane this grey pane revealed itself and now it won't go away. There's no way to resize it, and switching to other views doesn't make it go away either.

Is there a way to reset *just* the view from the settings file(s), so as to not to lose all my *other* account settings and profile data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

nm, [found it](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=291015&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a). http://gemal.dk/mozilla/files.html

> localstore.rdf Defines default windows settings. Saved persistent values. Info about toolbars, size, positions, etc

Answer (score 0):

`Localstore.rdf` is indeed the right file to look at.

I have Ubuntu installed and all i had to do is open a Terminal window and type

`locate localstore.rdf`

to find the location of the file.

Don't know if it is present in Windows.

All I had to do then is to copy it to a different filename (for backup) and then remove the original localstore.rdf.  Then restart Thunderbird and voila! It comes up with the default view setting that you can customize to your needs again.

Should this routine get you into trouble then restore from backup.